# Sharing names between CSS/Javascript/View Templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Whats the easiest/most-elegant way to share names between javascript, stylesheets and view templates? Should it be done using variables defined in some initializer file? I heard Ryan Bates talk about js.coffee.erb having some issues (with the .erb and ruby in it) in one of his railscasts (he did not mention what the issues were).

x.html.erb - `<div id="awesomediv">Awesome</div>`

x.css.scss - `#awesomediv {background-color: #333333}`

x.js.coffee - `$('#awesomediv').text("You are awesome")`

Whats the best way to organize and dry up all the "awesomediv" names spread out across the files? I believe I've seen DHH use variables in one of his demos at RailsConf but I didn't follow his directory structure or how he organized the different files with variables.

In case I need to change the name "awesomediv" to "veryawesomediv", I have to change it many different locations/files. Even a moderate size application will have to make such changes over time.

I am looking for best practices/something that has worked well for others in managing this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the rails_conf gem, which gives you access to a Settings object in all views/controllers. So in the css.erb you could have

```
#<%= Settings.tag_ids.awesome %> {
  //css rules
}
```

This works in rails 3.1 or greater I think.

Then in a javascript file that is included in all layouts do

```
tag_ids = <%= Settings.tag_ids.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

Then your js can refer to them as

```
tag_ids.awesome
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look at this gem. It appears like this gem will work by adding variables in JS files. However, since all information is available at pre-process/compile time, I would like to see all variables resolved at compile time right out of the gate when deployed rather than have some dependencies at runtime in the JS engine.

Comment: Yeah i tend to make a very small separate js file that only has variables